# Can Identityserver3 act as a Identity Provider with SAML (C#, MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml, identityserver3

I want to implement SSO using C#, SAML

According to what I read on internet,

IdentityServer3 can be act as Service Provider with Kentor Authservice.
https://coding.abel.nu/2015/01/saml2-for-thinktecture-identityserver-3-with-kentor-authservices/

(***My understanding -> Service Provider will check SAML token and allow user to access resource/website/webpage***)

But Can IdentityServer3 act as a IdentityProvider IdP with SAML?

(***My understanding -> Identity Provider IdP will authenticate user against database and pass the identity of user in form of SAML token***)

Can anybody please tell me whether IdentityServer3 can be act as a Identity Provider with SAML token?  If not how can I approach the same? Do I have to create my own Idp and create SAML token?

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am quite new to this.

Any link / help would be appreciated.

P.S. - I am creating new question as my reputation not allowing me to comment on existing question. :(

Answer (score 0):

No, IdentityServer3 can't act as a SAML2 Idp. It would require a SAML2 plugin to be built. There have been discussions on creating such a plugin based on Kentor.AuthServices, but so far nobody has had the time (or money to sponsor) to build that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please guide me with any link/post about how can i approach, if I want to build SAML2 Idp?